# Firebase Admin SDK Android

Tags: android, firebase-admin

Code for Initialising Firebase-Admin SDK in Android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_excel);

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("android.resource://com.app.hello/raw/hello.json");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseOptions options = null;
    try {
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://hello.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);



}
```

Error while building the app for run:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)
```

error: incompatible types: FirebaseOptions cannot be converted to Context
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Comment: can u share it,how to use it in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin SDK cannot and should not be used on Android. It is for server-side and other back-end environments only.

Comment: Solved it by making a java project in android studio

Comment: @groupwork can you please share some link or video so that we can refer as per your comment.